# how to put multiple subplots in one figure with only two axes

Tags: matlab

I have a figure with multiple subplots, i.e subplot(3,4,12).
I wonder how can this subplots can be represented as a "single figure" for example to reduce the gap between the subplots and have only one x and y axes label although each subplot can be "read" independently.

thank you in advance
Kind Regards
D Marini

Comment: You can use tight_subplot to manipulate the gaps between subplots
https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27991-tight-subplot-nh--nw--gap--marg-h--marg-w-/content/tight_subplot.m. It won't represent them as a single Figure but you can basically remove the gaps if you want.

Comment: Subplot also returns a handle, which you can use to adjust the positioning via `set(subplot(3,4,12),'Position',[...])`. Alternatively, create the subplots by hand by calling `axes`. I guess this is exactly what the tight_subplot does that schvaba was pointing out.

Comment: If you truly want one x-axis and one y-axis. You should use use regular ´plot´ and ´hold on´. If you truly want 3x4 subplots, you need four x-axes and three y-axes, unless all twelve subplots would happen to be in the right place in the axes.

Comment: thankyou for the comments. That seems to be a nested function, as a such it should be contained within a paren function. I couldnt manage to run that example, consequently not able to implement in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want x and y axes only on the leftmost and bottom subplots, try the following:

```
figure
hold on
n = 12;
ax = gobjects(n,1);
for k = 1:n
pos = [0.1+0.2*(mod(k-1,4)), 0.65-0.3*floor(k/4-0.01), 0.2, 0.3];
ax(k) = subplot(3,4,k,'Position',pos);
end
set(ax(1:8),'XTick',[])
set(ax([2:4 6:8 10:12]),'YTick',[])
```